# Isn't this conflict of interest?

Tags: validity, us5714045

Patent 5714045 has been assigned to the FDOT and they use this product in every pier repair in their territory. It feel like a circular formula when programming in excel.... I "invent" it and patent it and then I specify it for use in my infrastructure??? Puzzled

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, I'm extremely unclear on what you're asking here. But there are certainly no issues with someone using a patent that they are granted. In fact, in a majority of cases that's really the purpose of patents. Not all, mind you, but that's what I'd probably describe as the "purest use" of the patent system.

I did a quick (admittedly, very quick) search online to find the circumstances you're describing, and couldn't find anything. Perhaps it would help if you explained a bit more of what's going on and which part is confusing you, I could help get you a better answer.